# How can I make swap function faster in c++ ?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am writing a couple string sort algorithm with c++ and I wonder if I can make this swap operation faster.

```
void swap(string *items,int a, int b ){
        string temp;
        temp = items[a];
        items[a] = items[b];
        items[b] = temp;
}
```

I'll be appreciate if you can help...

Comment: Have you determined that it is the bottleneck for the performance of your program? Why do you think it is slow?

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" ~Donald Knuth

Comment: I am guessing it's the amount of swap calls your sorting algorithm needs to make that makes it slow, not the swap operation itself

Comment: You could declare it inline, since the code is rather small. It will save you a function call, the code will run faster, but it will increase the size of your executable by a small amount.

Comment: There are three entire string copies occurring for each swap, so it's definitely realistic to assume this will cause problems if the strings are long.

Comment: @dauphic: Assigning `string` objects does not necessarily copy the data, depending on the details of the implementation. For example, a reference-counted copy-on-write implementation could avoid the string data copies.

Comment: @dauphic Good implementations of std::string are not going to do a deep copy, therefore the above is micro optimization.

Comment: @GregHewgill, @VJo: Visual Studio doesn't do this, as far as I can tell, and I don't believe libstdc++ does this either, unless you explicitly give both `std::string` instances the same allocator.

Comment: Disregard, I see what gcc is doing.

Comment: "Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified" — Donald Knuth

Answer (score 20, accepted):

String class has its own swap function.

```
items[a].swap(items[b]);
```

It's the fastest way to do this because it accesses the string internals and avoids all copying.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/swap).

Comment: This is the best answer so far, +1

Comment: I totally forgot that `std::string` supported swap, this is probably the best solution if you don't have rvalue references (and just as good if you do).

Comment: Note that Greg's answer guarantees that this function will be used.

Comment: Note that this is what the more general `std::swap()` does internally.

Comment: @sth The reason why specific classes have a method that have a function with the same name in STL, is because those methods are faster for the particular class, than for the general STL template function. I read it in a book somewhere.

Comment: @xcrypt: The general function should call the specific class method when appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `std::swap()`:

```
void swap(string *items, int a, int b) {
    std::swap(items[a], items[b]);
}
```

But there's no guarantee that this will be measurably faster, and this probably isn't the slow part of your code anyway. Have you measured the performance of the swap operation compared to the rest of your code?

Comment: Would you even expect `std::swap` to be faster? If so why? But most definitely use `std::swap` and indeed there's no need to write your own wrapper to it, just call it directly.

Comment: I almost think this should be a comment instead of an answer, since the question is how to make it faster, and you mention that there is no guarantee this will be faster. In fact, this probably does exactly the same thing as he's already doing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I would expect `std::swap` to be faster, especially in C++11 where the move constructor semantics could do better than three assignments.

Comment: that should go in the answer surely

Comment: +1 for getting the right answer, even if you didn't know that it's right ;-) 21.3.7.8 of C++03 says that `std::swap` is overloaded for strings, and it calls the `swap` member function. 21.3.5.8 guarantees that this is constant time. No nonsense with move semantics. We can't be absolutely sure that it's faster than the questioner's code, what with the possibility of COW or other optimizations saving the questioner's code from the expected `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the strings. But it's pretty likely to be better and it's certainly not bad.

Answer (score 6):

Use `std::swap`; it will do the best job it can. If your compiler supports C++11's rvalue references, this means that it will take advantage of move semantics to avoid the copy that occurs in your swap function.

However, if your compiler doesn't support rvalue references, it will most likely perform the same way as your swap function does.

Most standard library implementations will implement `std::swap` as something similar to:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T temp(std::move(a));
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(temp);
}
```

The `std::move` function will return an rvalue reference (T&&) to the variable passed in. When you attempt to assign this rvalue reference, it will invoke the type's move operator, if one is available. If a move operator isn't available, it will invoke the copy operator as usual.

In the case of `std::string`, the above swap function will do no string copies with C++11; only the internal data, such as the string length and C string pointer, will be copied. Without C++11, it will perform three copies of the actual string contents.

Comment: Anyway there's an overload of `std::swap` for strings. 21.3.7.8 of C++03 or 21.4.8.8 of C++11. So it is not true that "Without C++11, it will perform three copies of the actual string contents".

Answer (score 4):

You could change your algorithm to work on elements of type `string*` instead of `string`. Then all the assignments in your `swap` function would operate on pointers, and be faster because no string copying would be involved.